# Immersive screen

Tags: screen, sticky, android-immersive

I use the following code for immersive sticky screen.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

@Override **//Here is get this notification that method does not overide 
            method from its superclass. If i remove the @Override and run the app it still runs work but without the immersive screen. How can i get it to work    

  public void onWIndowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    if(hasFocus){
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                |View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                |View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                |View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                |View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                |View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
    }
```

}
}
Kindly need your help.. Thank You

Comment: `onWIndowFocusChanged` - you've spelt "Window" with capital-W, capital-I, not lower-case-i!

Comment: thanks..i feel so silly..